# Reload/Refresh IFrame without have a white flash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I have a iFrame which loads many different pages, the initial load is always fine as i hide the IFrame until content is loaded then only do i display the IFrame.

My problem is now i have some pages which need to postback to grab information out the database dependent on what a user has on that page.

When this happens i get a white page while content is loaded. I cant hide the page as this would look worse then having a white loading page, i just need it to sit still with no flash while its drop down box populates.

I'm up for any solution using JS JQ or C# and my project is in ASP.

How i call my page refresh:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

I call the refresh from inside the iFrame (Name: IFrameDam)

I am able to hid my IFrame from with in its self if this sparks any idea's:

```
$('#IFrameDam', window.parent.document).hide();
```

Comment: show a loader maybe if you are after UI?

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to update? Is it a list of tabular data or similar, or some kind of generated content? Maybe using an AJAX request and rendering the data client side might be a better solution.

Comment: @Tim The data must be binded to Custom Dropdowns, this is done in the page load with C#, these dropdowns don't allow JS Or Jquery to bind data to them, so a whole page refresh is needed to bind new data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax request instead iframe and update the contents inside iframe parent div with id #IFrameDam and set the timer to resend ajax request and update without white screen. This behavior is same for almost any browser whereas iframe loads a whole new page inside current page leaving a blank space when not loaded.

here's how you can achieve this using ajax and jquery.
Just put iframe src path after "request_page" and refresh time after "time" variables.

Follow this link: http://jsbin.com/EYIKAnAb/1/edit?js